# Downloading most recent PDF in Issuu

Tags: xml, json, pdf, download, issuu

So I have managed to come up with a URL using the Issuu API to get most all of the information about the latest PDF I have uploaded. The problem is that I want to be able to get the URL to download that PDF. How do I determine the URL to download the PDF with the following given information.

This is the response I get after using the `issuu.documents.list` action and a few other argument to sort and limit the results and whatnot (I've provided both the XML and JSON responses just for kicks and giggles):

**XML Response**:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
    <result totalCount="257" startIndex="0" pageSize="1" more="true">
        <document
            username="thecrimsonwhite"
            name="09.14.11"
            documentId="110914053847-872eaa6e8f844601b0ef763d5332f7eb"
            title="The Crimson White"
            access="public"
            state="A"
            type="007000"
            orgDocType="pdf"
            orgDocName="09.14.11.pdf"
            downloadable="true"
            origin="singleupload"
            pro="F"
            rating="0.0"
            ratingsAllowed="true"
            commentCount="0"
            commentsAllowed="true"
            bookmarkCount="0"
            viewCount="71"
            pageCount="8"
            gfx="7"
            dcla="2|b|8|||810|1476|0|0"
            ls="1"
            ep="1315976400"
            publishDate="2011-09-14T05:00:00.000Z"
            description="The Crimson White is a student-created publication that aims to inform, entertain the University of Alabama and surrounding Tuscaloosa areas.">
            <tags>
                <tag value="news"/>
                <tag value="white"/>
                <tag value="sports"/>
                <tag value="lifestyles"/>
                <tag value="opinions"/>
                <tag value="crimson"/>
            </tags>
        </document>
    </result>
</rsp>
```

**JSON Response**:

```
{"rsp":{"_content":{"result":{"totalCount":257,"startIndex":0,"pageSize":1,"more":true,"_content":[{"document":{"username":"thecrimsonwhite","name":"09.14.11","documentId":"110914053847-872eaa6e8f844601b0ef763d5332f7eb","title":"The Crimson White","access":"public","state":"A","type":"007000","orgDocType":"pdf","orgDocName":"09.14.11.pdf","downloadable":true,"origin":"singleupload","pro":"F","rating":0.00000e+0,"ratingsAllowed":true,"commentCount":0,"commentsAllowed":true,"bookmarkCount":0,"viewCount":71,"pageCount":8,"dcla":"2|b|8|||810|1476|0|0","ep":1315976400,"publishDate":"2011-09-14T05:00:00.000Z","description":"The Crimson White is a student-created publication that aims to inform, entertain the University of Alabama and surrounding Tuscaloosa areas.","tags":["news","white","sports","lifestyles","opinions","crimson"]}}]}},"stat":"ok"}}`
```

The URL on the download button for this particular document is `http://document.issuu.com/110914053847-872eaa6e8f844601b0ef763d5332f7eb/original.file?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJY7E3JMLFKPAGP7A&Expires=1316073684&Signature=r34xY8RUJYNxTL8X3SSedAWxDxk%3D`

What is the `AWSAccessKeyID` and `Expires` attributes? I understand that the signature is a calculated MD5 sum (though, I don't know if it's any different than the alorithm at [Signing Requests](http://issuu.com/services/api/signingrequests.html)).

This is critical for an application that I am developing that displays the most recent PDF edition of my company's newspaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWSAccessKeyId](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--what-is-my-aws-access-and-secret-key.html) is the Amazon Web Service(AWS) access key.

Its not the same as "API key", which you can request [here](http://issuu.com/services/).

So may be using the same AWS key will work for all documents.

The Expires attribute is [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28geology%29) date time. When you hit the URL you have to send the current or future date/time in epoch as expires attribute value. You can generate it in epoch format [here](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm)

Signature is same as given in [Signing Requests](http://issuu.com/services/api/signingrequests.html), do you know any tool to generate it online ?

Let me know if it helps.

-Arun Jain

Comment: Hmm. Now that I look at it, the link I provided does not use the same signature. With the API, I'd use MD5 which yields a hexadecimal value. The signature in the above link is not in hexadecimal. Thanks for indicating what the AWSAccessKeyId and Expires attributes are.