# Downloading PDFs from ISSUU

Tags: issuu

I am trying to download publication from ISSUU, directly as PDF.

So for example take this URL:

https://issuu.com/vaistinecamelia/docs/camelia_2018_spalis_elvariantas_kre

Any ideas how I could access it?

There is 3rd party services, that do it, like so:
http://issuu.pdf-downloader.com/, so I presume it must be possible somehow

However I want to do it directly Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I did not find a way directly download PDF, but there is a way around it.

So basically each publication has a twiter meta tag:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://image.isu.pub/180721061958-e8f19464b7540f48371102c2b71136b4/jpg/page_1.jpg">
```

So you can access each and every page by looping through URLs, until you get no valid image, by changing the end (page_1.jpg, page_2.jpg and so on).

Once you have all the images, it is easy to convert them to PDF, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried and reviewed all GitHub Issuu downloaders and came to conclusion. That JPG page download is only possible. SWF page download is killed (disabled) by Issuu as Flash has died. PDF page download don't work, too.
Only option to download Full PDF if somebody hack access keys generation (AWSAccessKeyId, Expires, Signature) [Issuu - Signing requests](https://developer.issuu.com/signing-requests/) [Stack Overflow - some talk about access keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427071/downloading-most-recent-pdf-in-issuu)

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/document.issuu.com/{documentId}/original.file?AWSAccessKeyId=x&Expires=x&Signature=x
```

Any suggestion are welcome how to download higher quality than JPGs.